# Calling Java API from Scala with null argument

Tags: scala, null, java, scala-option

I have some Scala code that needs to call a Java API

The Java API takes arguments that may be null.  My Scala, of course, uses `Option`.

For example, let's say I have a Java object constructor `Foo(Integer)` where the `Integer` may be `null`.  I want to call it given a Scala `bar: Option[Int]`.

I tried this

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val foo = Foo( bar.getOrElse(null) )
```

But got this compile error

```
Error:(335, 44) type mismatch;
  found   : Any
  required: Integer
  bar.getOrElse(null),
```

What is the correct idiom for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sooner do I post the question, than I spot the answer in the related list (sorry)

Here's a solution

```
val foo = Foo(bar.getOrElse(null).asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer])
```

Kind of clunky.  Anyone have anything better?

Comment: The complaint I have this this solution is that `asInstanceOf` masks type errors. If `bar` is an `Option[String]`, this compiles but throws `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a Java method to reproduce this problem:

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> class Foo(a: java.lang.Integer)
defined class Foo

scala> val bar: Option[Int] = Some(5)
bar: Option[Int] = Some(5)

scala> new Foo(bar.getOrElse(null))
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: Integer
              new Foo(bar.getOrElse(null))
                                   ^
```

The problem is that `Int` can't be `null`, so the type of `bar.getOrElse(null)` is `Any`.

```
scala> bar.getOrElse(null)
res0: Any = 5

scala> bar.orNull
<console>:15: error: Cannot prove that Null <:< Int.
              bar.orNull
                  ^
```

So you've got to convert the `Option`'s type parameter to something that can be `null` before you unwrap it in a nullable way.

Quickest way I can think of immediately:

```
scala> new Foo(bar.map(x => x: java.lang.Integer).orNull)
res18: Foo = Foo@cdc45e
```

---

Edit: Here, I thought of a more general way to do it!

```
implicit class RichOption[A](o: Option[A]) {
    def toRef[B >: Null](implicit f: A => B): B = o.map(f).orNull
}
```

Now you can write `new Foo(bar.toRef)` :)

Comment: Thank you Chris.  I understand now.  I wonder if some implicit could/should be added JavaConverters to make calling Java easier, and avoid the temptation to use NULL in your Scala code ;-)

Comment: Thumbs up, but I would call it `toRef`. `x.toRef[Integer]`. The SO nanny doesn't allow increment operator in comments. It's weird being back in Kindergarten, the chairs are so small.

Answer (score 3):

More chatter:

```
scala> import runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger
import runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger

scala> val x = Some(42)
x: Some[Int] = Some(42)

scala> val y: Option[Int] = None
y: Option[Int] = None

scala> x.fold(null: Integer)(boxToInteger)
res0: Integer = 42

scala> y.fold(null: Integer)(boxToInteger)
res1: Integer = null
```

Of course it's better to

```
scala> x.fold(null: Integer)(i => i: Integer)
res2: Integer = 42
```

and even better

```
scala> x.fold[Integer](null)(identity)
res3: Integer = 42

scala> y.fold[Integer](null)(identity)
res4: Integer = null
```